# Generic structuration of a web form and a MySQL's table for saving a array of undefined length

Tags: php, html, sql

In a web form i will ask the user for their job experiences, this data will have no fixed lenght. I need to let the user insert all the items he needs, every item will content 3 fields; job title, description and year.

My firts problem is, **how can i ask in the html form for the items?** i mean, whats the best way to ask items with no fixed lenght using html/php (and maybe ajax)? I saw some sites that have a button (add one) when you hit it a new item slot is showed, but i have no idea of how to implement this, **an example will be sufficient**.

The second part is, **how can i managed the data flow in post or get?**, until now, i only use fixed fields, so i always know in my php script how many post or get vars i will get. How can i use multiple POST vars without knowing the amount of them?

And the last one (and the more important), **how will be the best structure for my table in MySQL?** If i get multiple items for a fixed table where i will have all my users, how can i resolve the multiple items issue? For example, if my table is:

```
User  |   password    |    job_experiences
admin |   root        |    (this is just a cell, how can i save multiple items here?)    
jonh  |   1234        |    (this is just a cell, how can i save multiple items here?)
```

Thanks for any help!!!!

Comment: Take a look at something I did a while back [Workstream Hiring](http://www.workstreamautomation.com/hiring/) select any job and take a look at the form. If this is the kind of thing you are looking for I can tell you how I did it (assuming you can't figure it out). In the DB, the multiple items I just save as delimited lists (pipe delimited). However since then I've discovered [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_(markup_language)) which allows for tables and I would just use that and save it in the DB that way just use a PHP Textile parser to generate the html.

Answer (score 1):

Those are 3 questions, and it's best to post 3 questions, instead of discussing all of them. I will post the basics, and if you have specific questions, ask.

First, use button to add, and a JavaScript to clone an existing row (which can have more then one input field). For fieldnames use something like `company_name[]` - the `[]` is the important part, at this will send the field as an array. If you are editting profile, you can use `company_name[$id]` to preserve the mapping.

Second, in PHP you will receive this as `$_POST['company_name']` which will be numeric array with all the company names. Or if you specify $id - with the corresponding keys. So, you have to loop trough all `company_names`, if there are other fields - you retrieve them the same way, using the current key. Example:

```
for (i =0; i<$_POST['comany_name'].length;i++) {
   $company = $_POST['comany_name'][$i];
   $start_year = $_POST['from'][$i];
   ...
}
```

Next, you need 1 table for the users (username, password), and another for job experiences (userid, company, description, from, to). This is called `1:M` relation